# Tedious differential equation, solving for when $y(t) = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

If I have the differential equation:

$$\begin{cases}
\pi(2\,y\,R-y^2)\frac{dy}{dt}=-\pi\,r^2\sqrt{2\,g\,y} \\
y(0) = R \\
y'(0) < 0
\end{cases}$$

Where $r, R,$ and $g$ are all constants.

If I want to find when $y(t) = 0$, is there any easy method for doing this? **NB:** The solution for this differential equation is very tedious; using Wolfram and plugging in values for $r, R,$ and $g$ gives a *numerical* solution which is very long.

I found one solution at [this site](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DrainageOfAHemisphericalTank/) (see details); however, I don't understand how he integrates the equation (would love a step-by-step) , and also how it is true that the $t$ I'm seeking equals:

$\dfrac{14/15\,R^{5/2}}{r^2\sqrt{2\,g}}$

I do know that a regular function $y(x) = -3x+6$ means that

$$y(t)=0 \iff 0 = 3x + 6 \iff x = -2$$

How does this translate to differential equations? His last step in *DETAILS* just seems like a big statement without anything to back it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did he find the solution? I don't know. But you can verify that it IS the solution by differentiating and seeing that it satisfies the equation, and then also checking that at time $0$ the value for $y$ is indeed $R$.

Actually, I think that I *do* know. He divided both sides by $\sqrt{y}$ to get

\begin{align}
\pi(2y^\frac{1}{2}R-y^\frac{3}{2}) dy=-\pi r^2\sqrt{2g} dt
\end{align}
and then integrated both sides to get
\begin{align}
\pi(2\frac{2}{3}y^\frac{3}{2}R-\frac{2}{5}y^\frac{5}{2}) =-\pi r^2\sqrt{2g} t + C \text{, i.e.}\\
\pi(\frac{4}{3}y^\frac{3}{2}R-\frac{2}{5}y^\frac{5}{2}) =-\pi r^2\sqrt{2g} t + C \text{, i.e.}\\
\frac{4}{3}y^\frac{3}{2}R-\frac{2}{5}y^\frac{5}{2} =- r^2\sqrt{2g} t + C'
\end{align}

As for the second part, once you've found an equation relating $y$ to $t$ (but not involving $y'$!) you can set $y$ to zero and see what this implies about $t$.

In this case, the formula given is 
\begin{align}
\frac{4}{3} R y^\frac{3}{2} - \frac{2}{5} y^\frac{5}{2} = -r^2 \sqrt{2g} t + \frac{14}{15} R^\frac{5}{2}
\end{align}
Setting $y = 0$ gives 
\begin{align}
\frac{4}{3} R 0^\frac{3}{2} - \frac{2}{5} 0^\frac{5}{2} = -r^2 \sqrt{2g} t + \frac{14}{15} R^\frac{5}{2}\\
0 = -r^2 \sqrt{2g} t + \frac{14}{15} R^\frac{5}{2}\\
 r^2 \sqrt{2g} t = \frac{14}{15} R^\frac{5}{2}\\
  t = \frac{1}{r^2 \sqrt{2g}}\frac{14}{15} R^\frac{5}{2}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Perfect! Couldn't ask for more :)

Comment: Note, BTW, that solving for $y$ is a horrible pain, but as is often the case in these equations, finding a formula for $y$ in terms of a formula for $t$ (like $\sin y^2 + e^y = t^3 + t$) is often relatively easy via "separation of variables" and this implicit relation between $y$ and $t$ can then tell you a good deal (as in this example).